# Upstart problem with virtualenv - Python/Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv, upstart

I'm using upstart in order to start this script:

```
pre-start script
    sudo export WORKON_HOME=~/.envs
    sudo source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
    sudo workon env1
end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

exec python /home/radiant/www/staging/django_project/manage.py celerycam > /home/radiant/www/staging/logs/celerycam.log

respawn

respawn limit 10 90
```

---

Without the `pre-start script` it works, with the script block I get this:

> start: Job failed to start

---

### My fix:

Instead of sourcing using the Virtual Environment's python interpreter works fine :)

should have thought about this before!

---

Any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be what `~` resolves to when running under Upstart. Try specifying an absolute path for `WORKON_HOME` and check that the user the job runs as has permissions to all relevant directories and files.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an upstart expert - but I think the problem is that you're trying to sudo those commands.  If upstart is using the stock "sudo", you're trying to run shell functions as commands - which you can't do.

Try dropping the sudo part of this to see if it works.

```
pre-start script
    export WORKON_HOME=~/.envs
    source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
    workon env1
end script
```